# Changing to llvm compiler when deploying iPhone app

Tags: iphone, deployment, llvm-gcc

I found this:

[Changing Compiler to llvm-clang on existing iPhone Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412882/changing-compiler-to-llvm-clang-on-existing-iphone-project)

But that does not help.

I am still getting the error. Setting the BaseSDK to the iPhoneSimulator 3.1 seems to work. But I don't think this is the right thing to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the answer and comments on that question, you'll see that there is not yet a version of LLVM that will target the iPhone device.  You can target the iPhone Simulator using LLVM GCC, with some fiddling, because that is running on a Mac.  Even though LLVM can target the ARM platform, Apple has indicated that it's not yet ready for use in deploying to the iPhone.