# Building an iPhone OS 2.2.1 project fails with error

Tags: iphone, compiler-construction

Maybe someone knows what this means?

```
error: can't exec '/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2' (No such file or directory)
```

I wanted to use LLVM GCC 4.2 compiler because an Apple guy said that's the best one. I guess LLVM GCC 4.2 does not work with iPhone OS 2.2.1 framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I respond [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525510/changing-to-llvm-compiler-when-deploying-iphone-app/1526911#1526911) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525510/changing-to-llvm-compiler-when-deploying-iphone-app), LLVM is not yet ready to compile applications targeted at the iPhone for any version of the SDK.  You can use it to build for the iPhone Simulator, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412882/changing-compiler-to-llvm-clang-on-existing-iphone-project), because you are building for the Mac in that case.

I would expect it to be available soon with a new release of the iPhone SDK, given the rapid pace of improvement with the LLVM compiler and Clang parser.

Answer (score 1):

Correct. That compiler only works with 3.0 and up I think.

Comment: Actually, LLVM does not yet work for any version of the SDK targeted at the device.  See my answer for more.